# Bootstrap collapse not collapsing element

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

I just implement the code of collapse from w3schools (light code than the bootstrap website .. I've tried this one also) and the collapse element isn't displayed

I'm using angular 9, bootstrap 4 and I've installed JQuery

here is the code :

```
<p>
    <button class="btn btn-info m-3" type="button">Add Invoice</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary m-3" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#searchBloc">
         Search
    </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="searchBloc">
    <div class="card card-body">
           Search Form
    </div>
</div>
```

i've add the jquery cdn in my index.html :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
         integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
         crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5kjh4t) to show the issue happening?

Comment: I would suggest installing [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io), which doesn't need jQuery. You can then use its [ngbCollapse directive](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples).

Comment: i've installed before ng-bootstrap

Comment: If you want to use jquery with angular (I suggest you don't) make sure you have also included bootstrap.min.js.

Comment: i'll use ngbCollapse, i dont know before that exist .. thank's for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just don't. Angular already have its own tools and you should avoid using jquery inside because it could not work as expected. For something like a collapse function, you can find plenty of npm package that will provide you this functionality and that are probably lighter than bootstrap. Just make a quick search on internet with `npm` as keywords and you'll find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is that you have to wrap all the content in same `div`.

All the content includes

1) The content which you are going to click

2) the content you want to display when `button` click

They both have to be wrap in same `div`

You have to include the `bootstrap js` also in order to make it work!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>


<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>



<div>
  <p>
    <button class="btn btn-info m-3" type="button">Add Invoice</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary m-3" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#searchBloc">
      Search
    </button>
  </p>
  <div class="collapse" id="searchBloc">
    <div class="card card-body">
      Search Form
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error in bootstrap. 'collapse' doesn't work correctly. You need to type 'collpase'.
I'm working on a simple ReactJS project. I installed bootstrap 4.5.3. Collapse wasn't working correctly. When I typed 'className='collpase'' the collapse feature worked.

Comment: Is there an issue open for this error? If so you might want to link it in your answer so future readers can see if it has been fixed in the version they use.